# File download on Safari using response package: Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted

Tags: javascript, python, response

I want to download a file when the user clicks on a button. I implemented it through python flask with the response package as follows

```
bib_text = 'test'

filename = 'test_file'
response = make_response(bib_text)
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s.bib" % filename
return response
```

the code above works fine on Chrome, but on Safari the javascript console tells me the error

```
Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted
```

and instead of a .bib file it downloads a .bib.html file?
Any idea what is going on? Is there another way to do this which works for Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem can be solved by adding the following header specifications

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "must-revalidate"
response.headers["Content-type"] = "application/bib"
```

the Content-type specification is the important one